# Automatically add golang package names that are used but not imported to import statement

Tags: golang

Is there a way or tool in Emacs, specifically by use of **go-mode**, to automatically add the lines of code to the `import` statement, while writing code that uses those packages? Let us assume those packages is got by `go get` or in some other way at a time before, they are somewhere in the `src` dir or they are just built-in go packages.

Like, in following go program, two built-in packages are used, `os` and `fmt`; however only one of them are imported, `os`. While typing the first line in the main, that uses `fmt` package, is it possible some tool, existence is in question here, can add the package name to to `import`s.

```
package main

import (
    "os"
)

func getHome() {
    return os.Getenv("HOME")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("this is my go playground.")

    h := os.Getenv("HOME")
    g := os.Getenv("GOPATH")
    p := os.Getenv("PATH")

    getHome()

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You may use [goimports](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports) utility and just replace `gofmt` in go-mode with `goimports`. Cite from goimports page shows how to integrate it with go-mode:

```
(setq gofmt-command "goimports")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/you/somewhere/emacs/")
(require 'go-mode-load)
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'gofmt-before-save)
```

The recipe for use-package installer:

```
(use-package go-mode
:custom
(gofmt-command "goimports")
:hook
(before-save-hook gofmt-before-save))
```

Or if you have already worked go-mode then interactively

M-x `customize-group` go

and set value of `Gofmt command` to `gomimports`.